# Unexpected error coming from Helios library during connection to preview TestNet verification?

Tags: cardano-cli, javascript, helios

My Eternl wallet now has an account that is targeted towards the preview TestNet. I did activate the account for connecting to Cardano dApps. I am able to connect to my wallet from Picoswap. However, during the attempt to by the Helios library to verify the connection to the preview TestNet, I am getting an unexpected error report from the Helios library.

As you can see in the call stack sub-window from the screenshot below, this is occurring in the fromValidatorHash() method that belongs to the Address object. If you look in the Console sub-window you can see that the method was expecting the stakingHash parameter to be a StakeKeyHash object or if not that, a StakingValidator object. Instead that parameter is a ValidatorHash object so the assert() call fails and throws the error.

https://github.com/Hyperion-BT/picoswap

What can I do to fix this?

Also, can someone point me to the documents that describe the data objects the Helios library is trying to parse, in case I have to go it alone here?

[image]

Comment: Should be resolved now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to picoswap code base not being updated to use the latest Helios version (currently v0.11.2) correctly.  It was working on a prior Helios version around v0.9.x but picoswap is not currently in active development.

This issue was discussed on the Helios discord here: https://discord.com/channels/997177025972424815/1000828171161190470/1069692746304077884